# What is the wxPython Equivalent to Tkinter's Tk.iconbitmap?

Tags: user-interface, wxpython

So I'm learning wxPython and am converting an application I wrote in python + Tk to wxPython.  I'm new to the framework and have just read the [getting started page on the wxPython](http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started) site.  I'm wondering if anyone knows off-hand the wxPython equivalent for Tk.iconbitmap so that I can put a small image on the corner of the main window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be [wx.Icon](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Icon-class.html).

You can use [wx.TopLevelWindow.SetIcon()](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.TopLevelWindow-class.html#Icon) to apply one to your main window.